# Use of concat in rails index api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concatenation

I am working on a api in which i want data of different status in single array.

```
def filter_index_by_admin
  articles = []
  articles.concat(Article.pending.map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show})
  articles.concat(Current.user.articles.where(status: 'approved').map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show})
  articles.concat(Current.user.articles.where(status: 'rejected').map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show})
  articles.concat(Current.user.articles.where(status: 'saved').map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show(user_included: true, comments_included: true)})
  render json: { articles: articles }, status: :ok                                          
end
```

in above api there is an array in named articles in which i am concating the data 
in Third line i am getting the index of all articles created by all users which has status pending.

in Fourth line i am concating the current users articles with status **approved** and same in line Fifth with status **rejected** and line Sixth with status **saved**.

I know it is not a dirty code.

So, is there any way to do it in sophisticated way?

Comment: I think `Article.pending.or(Article.where(user_id: Current.user.id).where.not(status: :pending))` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
articles = Current.user.articles.where(status: ['pending', 'rejected', 'approved', 'saved']).map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show})
```

UPDATE

If you are using rails 5+

```
articles = Article.where(user_id: Current.uer.id, status: ['rejected', 'approved', 'saved']).or(Article.pending).map { |article| ArticlePresenter.new(article)._show})
```

Comment: I don't want  status 'pending ' with current user. All things are right but can you tell me that how I use your above mentioned code with status pending articles of all users.

Comment: What is your rails version?

Comment: Glad to know that. Please accept the answer if that's what you were looking for.